# c++ Memory Leakage - boost library

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, memory-leaks

I have observed a memory leakage in the following program:

```
// g++ -std=c++11 32_MyTime.cpp 
//
// valgrind --leak-check=full ./a.out 
//


#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class MyTime {
private:
  int year;
  int month;
  int day;
  int hour;
  boost::posix_time::ptime *ptrTime;
  void update() {
    year = ptrTime->date().year();
    month = ptrTime->date().month();
    day = ptrTime->date().day();
    hour = ptrTime->time_of_day().hours(); 
  }
public:
  ~MyTime() {
    if (ptrTime!=nullptr) delete ptrTime;
  }
  MyTime(int y, int m, int d, int h):year{y},month{m},day{d},hour{h} {
    ptrTime = new boost::posix_time::ptime(
    boost::gregorian::date(year, month, day),
    boost::posix_time::hours(hour));       
  }
  void addHours(int nHours) {
    if (ptrTime!=nullptr) delete ptrTime;
    ptrTime = new boost::posix_time::ptime(
        boost::gregorian::date(year, month, day),
        boost::posix_time::hours(hour+nHours));
    update();
  }
  int getYear()  const { return year; }
  int getMonth() const { return month; }
  int getDay()   const { return day; }
  int getHour()  const { return hour; }
  void set(int y, int m, int d, int h) {
    if (ptrTime!=nullptr) delete ptrTime;
    ptrTime = new boost::posix_time::ptime(
        boost::gregorian::date(y, m, d),
        boost::posix_time::hours(h));
    update();
  }
  time_t getSecSince() const {
    return (*ptrTime - boost::posix_time::ptime(boost::gregorian::date(1970, 1, 1))).total_seconds();
  }
  const boost::posix_time::ptime* getPTime() const {
    return ptrTime;
  }
  bool operator==(const MyTime& other) const {
    return *ptrTime==*other.getPTime();
  }
  bool operator!=(const MyTime& other) const {
    return !(*this == other);
  }
  bool operator<(const MyTime& other) const {
    return *ptrTime < *(other.getPTime());
  }
  bool operator<=(const MyTime& other) const {
    return *ptrTime <= *(other.getPTime());
  }
  bool operator>(const MyTime& other) const {
    return *ptrTime > *other.getPTime();
  }
  bool operator>=(const MyTime& other) const {
    return *ptrTime >= *other.getPTime();
  }
};

void test() {

    MyTime t1 {2016,5,21,17};
    MyTime t2 {2016,5,22,10};

    bool print = false;

    if (print) {
    cout << "From : " << *t1.getPTime() << endl;  // Memory leak
    cout << "To   : " << *t2.getPTime() << endl;  // Memory leak
    }

    cout << " t1 < t2  " << (t1<t2)  << endl;
        cout << " t1 > t2  " << (t1>t2)  << endl;
        cout << " t1 == t2 " << (t1==t2) << endl;
        cout << " t1 < t1  " << (t1<t1)  << endl;
        cout << " t1 > t1  " << (t1>t1)  << endl;
        cout << " t1 == t1 " << (t1==t1) << endl;


    while (t1<=t2) {
      if (print)
            cout << "> Time : " << *t1.getPTime() << "    " << t1.getSecSince() << endl;  // Memory leak
      int s = t1.getSecSince();
      t1.addHours(1);
    }


}

int main() {
  test();
}
```

I have analysed the program with `valgrind` and the class should be error free (from the point of view of memory leakage).

This instruction causes the leakage:

```
cout << "From : " << *t1.getPTime() << endl;  // Memory leak
```

but I do not understand why.
I assume that the boost library has no error. 
It could be some copy constructor (just an explanation attempt).

How could I avoid it?

It is not vital for me to solve the issue (the code is there just for debugging), but it important to understand why it happens to avoid similar error in the future.

**EDIT** The code as it is has no memory leakage. You have to turn on the printing to get the leakage: `print = true;`

**EDIT 2** 
Valgrind execution with `print = true;`

```
==22204== 
==22204== HEAP SUMMARY:
==22204==     in use at exit: 1,748 bytes in 31 blocks
==22204==   total heap usage: 223 allocs, 192 frees, 38,751 bytes allocated
==22204== 
==22204== LEAK SUMMARY:
==22204==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22204==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22204==      possibly lost: 619 bytes in 20 blocks
==22204==    still reachable: 1,129 bytes in 11 blocks
==22204==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22204== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==22204== 
==22204== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==22204== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 1 from 1)
```

Valgrind execution with `print = true;` and a LOT MORE `cout`:

```
==22277== HEAP SUMMARY:
==22277==     in use at exit: 1,748 bytes in 31 blocks
==22277==   total heap usage: 79,279 allocs, 79,248 frees, 15,972,927 bytes allocated
==22277== 
==22277== LEAK SUMMARY:
==22277==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22277==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22277==      possibly lost: 619 bytes in 20 blocks
==22277==    still reachable: 1,129 bytes in 11 blocks
==22277==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22277== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==22277== 
==22277== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==22277== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 1 from 1)
```

Valgrind execution with empty `main`:

```
==22211== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==22211== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==22211== Using Valgrind-3.10.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==22211== Command: ./a.out
==22211== 
==22211== 
==22211== HEAP SUMMARY:
==22211==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22211==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==22211== 
==22211== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==22211== 
==22211== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==22211== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 1 from 1)
```

Comment: Why are you using pointers ? You don't need to

Comment: Make `ptrTime` a `unique_ptr` and the compiler will tell you what you did wrong. Additionally it will simplify your code.

Comment: @concept3d: do you mean ptime ptrTime; instead of ptime* ptrTime; as private attribute? or in the cout?

Comment: *"If there is a `delete`, there probably is a bug."* Bjarne Stroustrup (from memory, but should be about right) Just don't use a pointer here, there is no need for that. Make the member a plain `boost::posix_time::ptime`.

Comment: @concept3d: thank you! the code looks much better. But the leakage is still there

Comment: Running this code under valgrind shows no memory leaks. What leads you to believe that this code leaks memory?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: you have to swith the bool ```print```. This is to show that the leakage is due to cout. I edit the post

Comment: valgrind claims a bunch of "still reachable" links, but still no definite leaks. Examining the code for boost::posix_time's operator<< overload for std::ostream shows some questionable code that executes a "new custom_ptime_facet();", but without any apparent `delete` in sight. I am not ready to proclaim this as a bug/memory leak in boost's library, but at the very least this is sloppy code, and simply reinforces my long-held belief that, despite their popularity, Boost libraries are crap. The first thing I always do after inheriting any codebase that uses Boost is to simply get rid of it.

Comment: On a somewhat related note, `MyTime` lacks user-defined copy-constructor and assignment operator. If you ever copy or assign an instance of that class, you'll end up with two instances holding the same pointer, which will inevitably lead to undefined behavior later (when one of them destroys it and the other tries to dereference it).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Thank you. Now I have deactivated (```= delete```) the two constructors, copy and move. I do not need them.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Isn't that facet passed to `std::locale`? From what I can tell from the documentation, `std::locale` takes ownership and uses reference counting on the facets to correctly deallocate. Irrespective of that, if there is a bug in a particular library, wouldn't it be more constructive to at least report, if not fix it, rather than dismissing the whole collection as "crap"? Considering number of the libraries in Boost have become part of the C++ standard, that seems like a rather harsh judgement.

Comment: @DanMašek - as I stated, this is a long-held belief of mine, based not specifically on these particulars, but a number of other factors. And just because something's in the standard, doesn't mean that it's not crap. People's Exhibit A: `std::vector<bool>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. The leak is a false report:

```
==20323== 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==20323==    at 0x4C2BBCF: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==20323==    by 0x4EC21FF: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==20323==    by 0x4010609: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:72)
==20323==    by 0x401071A: call_init (dl-init.c:30)
==20323==    by 0x401071A: _dl_init (dl-init.c:120)
==20323==    by 0x4000D09: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.21.so)
==20323==
```

As you can see it's allocated from some shared library initializer. If you remove all code from main, it remains the same.

For `print = true` I notice the leaked facets (that's by design).

---

Secondly, as others have said, don't do the `new` thing. There is no need to emulate <strike>the badness</strike> of Java and [invite all kinds of programmer error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37373944/c-memory-leakage-boost-library/37380396#comment62261844_37373944).

Just use a `ptime` member already. To be honest I don't even see why you'd duplicate the `year`, `month`, `day` and `hour` fields at all, but here you are:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c919836f9c4a4487)</kbd>**

I'd suggest removing all duplication in the first place:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6ff8d4a3a6e92002)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class MyTime : public boost::posix_time::ptime {

    using ptime = boost::posix_time::ptime;
    using date  = boost::gregorian::date;

  public:
    MyTime(short unsigned y, short unsigned m, short unsigned d, short unsigned h) 
        : ptime {date{y, m, d}, boost::posix_time::hours(h)}
    { }

    void addHours(int nHours) { *this += boost::posix_time::hours(nHours); }

    int getYear()  const { return date().year();  }
    int getMonth() const { return date().month(); }
    int getDay()   const { return date().day();   }
    int getHour()  const { return time_of_day().hours(); }

    // instead of set, just assign `v = { 2016, 5, 22, 9 }`
    time_t getSecSince() const { return (*this - ptime{date{1970, 1, 1}}).total_seconds(); }
};

void test() {

    MyTime t1{ 2016, 5, 21, 17 };
    MyTime t2{ 2016, 5, 22, 10 };

    bool print = false;

    if (print) {
        std::cout << "From : " << t1 << std::endl;
        std::cout << "To   : " << t2 << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << " t1 < t2  " << (t1 < t2)  << std::endl;
    std::cout << " t1 > t2  " << (t1 > t2)  << std::endl;
    std::cout << " t1 == t2 " << (t1 == t2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << " t1 < t1  " << (t1 < t1)  << std::endl;
    std::cout << " t1 > t1  " << (t1 > t1)  << std::endl;
    std::cout << " t1 == t1 " << (t1 == t1) << std::endl;

    while (t1 <= t2) {
        if (print)
            std::cout << "> Time : " << t1 << "    " << t1.getSecSince() << std::endl;
        int s = t1.getSecSince();
        t1.addHours(1);
    }
}

int main() {
    test(); 
}
```

### BONUS Alternative Design

Since `MyTime` is really just extra operations on `ptime` now, why not:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8dab4a9dfab90358)</kbd>**

```
using MyTime = boost::posix_time::ptime;
using MyDate = boost::gregorian::date;

MyTime make_hdate(short unsigned y, short unsigned m, short unsigned d, short unsigned h) {
    return { MyDate{ y, m, d }, boost::posix_time::hours(h) };
}

MyTime addHours(MyTime const &mt, int nHours) {
    return mt + boost::posix_time::hours(nHours); 
}

time_t getSecSince(MyTime const &mt) {
    return (mt - MyTime{ MyDate{ 1970, 1, 1 } }).total_seconds(); 
}
```

Comment: 1) Thank you very much. 2) I do not agree on one point. You say "If you remove all code from main, it remains the same." With empty ```main``` there is no initialization (see my edit2). 3) Your code is great. Especially the BONUS part. 4) Would it be possible to add a constructor ```MyTime(short unsigned y, short unsigned m, short unsigned d, short unsigned h)``` (as a replacement to ```make_hdate```)? I tried, without success. 5) why is ```make_hdate``` not static?

Comment: Oh 2) you don't need to agree, because I wrote that when I hadn't seen you wanted us to change the code to reproduce the relevant leak :) 5) it is static. It's not _file-static_ in the sense that it has external linkage.

Comment: 4) Everything is possible. [Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5b0a04b8f18b0649) I think this is bad design (again, emulating Java badness). The upshot is that you can't use `getSecSince` and `addHours` unless you copy the timestamp to a `MyTime` first. Best to just work with the most general, least restrictive datatypes if you can.

Comment: Point in case: if you wanted to [use time_iterator](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3b1d5f1f75fd0530) you couldn't have used `getSecSince` without constructing a temporary `MyTime` copy just for that purpose.

Comment: I like your Live Demo very much. I do not understand what is good and bad design. But if every thing is under a hat, is (from my point of view) good. That is why I asked you about the _static_. I meant ```make_hdate``` was a method (should have been ```static ... MyTime::make_hdate``` to be a method). Intuitively ```make_hdate``` as a function is more C and a constructor is more OOP (C++) (?!?).

Comment: The "?!?" is exactly justified there. I think you should update your intuition to modern C++ a bit. Inheritance is overrated. Free functions are part of a class interface and can extend it too: [The Interface Principle](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill02.htm) - by Herb Sutter